# Limit of $(1/n)^{(1/n!)}$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: limits

A computer algebra system told me that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^{1/n!} = 1
\end{equation}
How can I show this? I tried applying the exponential and logarithm to see that this is equal to
\begin{equation}
\exp \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{n!} \log \frac{1}{n} \right)
\end{equation}
But I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Do you know $\lim_{x\to0}x^x=1$ ?

Comment: Yes, I can do that using the above method and then applying L'Hopital's rule. How does that help me?

Comment: Then it equals $$\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{\left(\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\right)}=1^0=1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

For $n\ge 1 $, $n!\ge n$.  Therefore,

$$0>-\frac{\log(n)}{n!}\ge -\frac{\log(n)}{n}$$

Comment: Go Green, Go White!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by checking radius of convergent. 1/n! Will become 0 faster than 1/n. So we can conclude that the whole limit will becone 1.

Comment: This does not constitute a rigorous proof.